# Unexpected "your post does not match quality standards" message

Tags: support, status-completed, quality-content

I posted [this question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/184/69):

> **Скло (вкрилося конденсатом) - як сказати одним словом?**
>
> Підкажіть, будь ласка, слово, що вживається у побуті і означає "вкритися конденсатом", наприклад, коли в холодну погоду на склі осідає "туман" з вологи?
>
> [word-usage] [одним-словом] ( <-- its a tag line)

But was unable to submit it because a message popped up like "Your post does not meet our quality standards". It also said that I can improve it some way I don't remember, and it also said that it should be syntactically correct.

Does it really checks for the syntactical (or orthographical) correction? There were no syntax errors from Ukrainian standpoint, but many words were underlined with red wavy line like they are (possibly syntax checking was for Russian language). These words (in bold) are underlined as incorrect:

> **Скло** (**вкрилося** конденсатом) - як **сказати** одним словом?
>
> **Підкажіть**, будь ласка, слово, **що вживається** у **побуті і означає** "**вкритися** конденсатом", **наприклад**, коли в **холодну** погоду на **склі осідає** "туман" **з вологи**?

Or my question should be longer?

I posted it after adding the English version of the text.

Comment: Те, що ви побачили червоні підкреслення, то це ваші локальні налаштування браузера. Так, у мене таке часто буває на інших сайтах мережі. Мабуть це пов'язано з розміром. Якщо ви вважаєте, що ваше повідомлення достатнє, то ви можете просто вставити будь-що в кінець , як-от "абабагаламага" 10 разів. А після того як відправили, просто відредагувати повідомлення видаливши не значиму частину. Тільки, чур, я цього не казав.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that our quality controls are a bit too strict for this site and some of then need relaxing.

However, I don't think they are - the questions blocked as low quality seem to be very short and lack details, which is what we expect from any question.

I will bring this up with the site assigned CM to look into, however.

---

Update:

We have disabled a few of the question quality filters that do not make as much sense for this site (things like penalising for lack of ASCII, or writing broken English).

Comment: Adding "Thank you" (in English) to even shorterst one of these allowed them to pass the control.

Comment: Which is why I am saying the rules need to be looked at, possibly revised.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. I'm a bit worried about "status-bydesign" tag you've added to the question. Does it mean that the bug is marked as "wontfix" and won't be reviewed again? I've updated reproducing steps to stress that the problem is **not** in the length of a post, but in lack of latin letters (which is a strange requirement for the community with Cyrillic writing)

Comment: @NashBridges - what this means is that the quality checks (and the error message) are all working as designed. Therefore, there is nothing to fix with those. I have asked the community manager in charge of the site to check whether the quality settings are correct and make sense for the site - these will be adjusted if not (for instance, if there is a requirement for ASCII, it would be relaxed/removed for this site).

Comment: Now it is clear, thanks

Comment: So, the syntax was checked as well, but it was English syntax. It was one of the points of my original question. Thanks to both Nash Bridges and Oded!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. My question was:

> Чи має вираз “копати криниченьку” прихований зміст?

Text:

> На одній з видів (чорний гумор, непристойності) гри "Що? Де? Коли?"
>   було питання про прихований зміст вислову "копав криниченьку", який
>   має відношення до статевого акту. Самого питання, на жаль, вже не
>   пригадаю. Якщо не помиляюсь, воно стосувалось українських народних
>   пісень.
>
> Отже, питання: **Чи дійсно це так і чи є якісь підтвердження?**

User [Chizh](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/92/chizh) advised to modify the question so I changed the question:

> Чи має вираз “копати криниченьку” ідіоматичне значення дотичне
>   статевих зносин?

Text:

> На одній з видів гри "Що? Де? Коли?", тема якої "Чорний гумор,
>   непристойності" було питання про прихований зміст вислову "копав
>   криниченьку", який має відношення до статевого акту. Самого питання,
>   на жаль, вже не пригадаю. Якщо не помиляюсь, воно стосувалось
>   українських народних пісень.
>
> Отже, питання: **Чи дійсно це так і чи є якісь підтвердження?**

**So the answer is**: try to rephrase, extend your question, add references, examples of usage etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a SE bug related to Cyrillic (not being /A-Za-z/).

Here's the steps to reproduce:

1. Enter the subject "Перевірка того, що в тексті запитання мусять бути латинські літери".
2. Enter the body:

> Чи можна писати ініціали (поруч із прізвищем) разом чи потрібно ставити пробіл між ім'ям та по батькові?`
>
> Наприклад,
>
> > Л.П. Косач
>
> чи
>
> > Л. П. Косач
>
> Чи є якесь конкретне правило, яке це регулює?

3. Enter the tag "bug".
4. Hit the "Post your Answer", get the "Unexpected..." error message.
5. Replace the "Чи є якесь конкретне правило, яке це регулює?" (8 words, 45 chars with spaces) with "Do we have a rule for that?" (7 words, 27 chars with spaces), post again and everything is fine.

Note that SE checks *raw* body message (before converting markdown to HTML), so any hyperlink will be counted as well, thus passing the validation.

I'm not sure, should we escalate this to meta.SE.

**UPDATE**

Reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292273/353479).

Comment: Why not? Posting these problems on Ukrainian.Meta does not seem to make us closer to the solution.

Comment: @Artemix  I thought that [questions marked as "support"](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/33/please-add-support-of-cyrillic-tags) are reviewed by SE team

Comment: Once I was told that technical problems are reviewed only on main META. Seems it is true.

Comment: Previous cyrillic-related bugs were - missing support of cyrillic tags, and then - awarding tag bages for cyrillic tags incorrectly gives [tag:??????] bage - all of them were resolved only after posted on main META.

Comment: @Artemix  OK, I'll report then.

Comment: @Artemix - you are incorrect. Tagging anything with bug will surface it to the team, from any meta site.

Comment: @Oded Strange, this post was created a month ago with no visible reaction. And my previous experience (a couple years ago on Russian.SE) shows that technical issues were not resolved until posted on main Meta.

Comment: This isn't a technical issue (writing an answer now), @Artemix - it is likely that others that have seen this have not seen it as a bug, or have not given it high priority (we have a large bug queue).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [what Oded did](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/168/4) (thanks, Nash Bridges!), I think, we should make a separate page on the Meta with a screen-shot of the problem ([like here](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/142/4), so that a user can easily identify "yeah, that's exactly my problem") and **exacts steps to be checked/done** to solve it.

Smth like:

> Якщо Ви бачите таку проблему:
>   [image]
>
> 1. …
> 2. …
> 3. …

Although new users will unlikely get into that Meta post themselves — at least we can point them to it manually if we somehow get information that a specific person has that problem.

Comment: To my experience when a newcomer see such an error, s/he leaves the site and never returns :( This is why such validations are very dangerous.

Comment: @NashBridges, yeah. But we should do what we can.